# Purchase through points

Tags: 8, commerce, ubercart, userpoints

For ex. person A introduce person B and B register in drupal commerce/ubercart site.

Now I want give A 5 points that A can buy other products with him/her points.

How Can I do this in drupal 8?

Comment: If this was about D7, you could use a solution similar to what I described in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/197271/39516) ... So maybe just give it some time for the required modules to become available for D8 also?

Comment: I use drupal 8.

Comment: Who can help me?